# extend typescript array of object without modifying the source

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this List object, but later on the shape changed, I need an extra id property, but how to not modify List?

```
interface List {
    name: string //without adding id here
}

interface ListData {
    type: string
    lists: List[] //how to include id here?
}

const data: ListData = {
    type: 'something',
    lists: [{
        id: '1',
        name: 'alice'
    }, {
        id: '2',
        name: 'ja'
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [extend](https://www.typescripttutorial.net/typescript-tutorial/typescript-extend-interface/) the `List` interface

```
interface List {
  name: string //without adding id here
}

interface ListId extends List {
  id: string
}

interface ListData {
  type: string
  lists: ListId[]
}

const data: ListData = {
  type: 'something',
  lists: [{
    id: '1',
    name: 'alice'
  }, {
    id: '2',
    name: 'ja'
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `extends`  keyword for extend existing interface

```
interface ListWithId extends List {
  id: string;
}
```

or you can make id optional in existing `List` interface so if you already used it some where it was not affect any one.

```
interface List {
  name: string;
  id?: string;
}
```

**Note**: `?` is used to make property optional.

Answer (score 1):

to add alternative approach to previous answers

```
type ListWithId = List & {id: string};

interface ListData {
    type: string
    lists: ListWithId[] //how to include id here?
}
```

or, not pretty but works

```
interface ListData {
    type: string
    lists: (List & {id: string})[] //how to include id here?
}
```

Comment: I like the non pretty approach